# how to load database update with entity framwork code first

Tags: entity-framework

I do add,update,delete data with sql management

in my code,I use load() function.if add or delete data,after load the dbcontext.set().count() has refreshed.but update any fields,after load ,the dbcontext.set() data not refresh?

I use ef 4.4.0 with .net framework4.0

how to do?
thanks

Comment: how to do what ? What have you tried ? What errors do you get ?

Comment: update A set col2 = '2' where id = 1 do it in sqlserver managerment.then in my application,I context.set<T>().load();context.set<T>().find(……).I get the entity A's col2 is not 2,always the old value!

Comment: edit the question to show your code please

Comment: try reading the object first, or setting the ObjectState to modified. but with the code it is hard to know why

Comment: if I insert or delete data in table A.context.set<T>().load();context.set<T>().count is ok. only update not refresh.then I write code like this:public void RefreshData()
        {
            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
            objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, ctx.Set<T>().Local);
        } it is ok. But if I refresh many times the speed very slow.